# Chart code does not run when protection is on

Tags: excel, vba

Excel gives me the

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005):   Method 'Maximumscale' of
>   object 'Axis' failed

but only when I have the sheet protected.
Now, I also have the unprotect code on `ThisWorkbok` excel object, which looks like this:

```
Sheets("Charted").Protect Password:="123", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
```

My code is as below:

```
Sub SetAxes()

   Dim objCht As ChartObject, AxisOne As Long, AxisTwo As Long, RangeMin As Double
   Dim RangeMax As Double, rng As Range       

   For Each objCht In Sheets("Charted").ChartObjects

   AxisOne = Sheets("Charted").Range("$H$32").Value
   AxisTwo = Sheets("Charted").Range("$H$6").Value
   Set rng = Sheets("Charted").Range("H7:H31")

   RangeMin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)
   RangeMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)

      With objCht.Chart

            With .Axes(xlValue)
                If AxisOne > AxisTwo Then
                .MaximumScale = AxisOne + 2000000 + RangeMax
                .MinimumScale = AxisTwo - 2000000
                Else
                .MaximumScale = AxisTwo + 500000 - RangeMin  'Error Occurs on this line
                .MinimumScale = AxisOne - 2000000
                End If
              End With

      End With
   Next objCht
   Call HideZeroRows
End Sub
```

Anything unusual about this code?
It all occurs on the same sheet and I have it so macros are allowed to run so what is going on?
It is a waterfall bar chart with is why I even need this in the first place for full disclosure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to either unprotect, edit the chart and re-protect, or allow editing of objects in the protection settings.

Comment: `UserInterFaceOnly` only holds for the current session. Close and reopen the workbook, and this setting is ignored, so VBA can't operate on protected objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If sheet protection is configured to disallow edits, you can't modify a protected sheet: whether you're a user or a VBA procedure makes no difference: you need to un-protect the sheet before you can make any changes to it:

```
Dim wasProtected As Boolean
If theSheet.ProtectionMode Then
    wasProtected = True
    theSheet.Unprotect '...args...
End If

'modify everything you need to modify

If wasProtected Then theSheet.Protect '...args...
```

Comment: In this case there's no need for checking `ProtectionMode`. If sheet is unprotected, unprotecting it will not raise any errors (it's just like this line never existed).

Comment: @JohnyL the flag isn't for *before* making the changes, it's for *after*, to avoid protecting the sheet  if it wasn't protected in the first place. Dealing with exactly this at work, systematically protecting the sheet is annoying AF when you're testing things and don't want it to unconditionally protect it.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Can this work on `ThisWorkbook`? I have so many macros that target that sheet and probably more to follow.

Comment: @Remi a wotkbook doesn't have sheet protection, sheet protection is a sheet thing ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I know, but my OP asked why my protection didn't work from `ThisWorkbook`. I have 7 macros that run on that page and I tried your method. It works partially. Your post is an answer but I wish there was a good alternative. I will probably just turn this into a separate module and then call your code to save time...

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Out of curiosity, is `theSheet` a shortcut of some sort? I have been changing it to `Sheets("5")` but it would be cool if that was some unknown shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

You have to allow user to  "Edit Objects" in protection.

[image]

Comment: @Remi unprotect, modify, re-protect.